# Using return(null) in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am coming across a situation where I return null in my code - something like this...

```js
{
    MyRouteProps.map((prop, key) => {
        if (prop.path) {
            return (<Route
                path={prop.path}
                component={prop.component}
                key={key}
            />)
        } else {
            return (null)
        }
    })
}
```

I am weary of doing so but there are objects in my MyRouteProps array that effectively do not represent routes (it has a dual purpose in generating a menu item with some of the objects representing breaks in the menu items). Are there any best practices I should be cognizant of if I do so?

thanks for your opinions...

Comment: By the way, usually we would write `return null;`. Writing `return(null)` seems very weird because it looks like a function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you filter your array before actually transforming each element into a component?

Something like this

```
{MyRouteProps
   .filter(prop => prop.path !== undefined)
   .map((prop, key) => (
      <Route 
        path={prop.path}
        component={prop.component}
        key={key}
      />
    )
}
```

This greatly improves readability of the code

Comment: It should also improve performance when the component is something more complex than a `Route`. Avoid having to have hooks defined (and ultimately unused) before the component returns `null` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

`null` is exactly the right thing to return when you don't want to render anything, [per the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#preventing-component-from-rendering).  You're fine!